# PHP adding array of text files into database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

Hello all I have been beating my head on the desk for days trying to figure this out, I am totally stumped.

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Add and Delete rows dynamically with textboxes using jQuery | Media Milan</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page_container">
        <div class="form_container">
            <h3>Add and Delete rows dynamically with textboxes using jQuery:</h3>
            <form action="addemp.php"  method="post">
                <table id="expense_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>CompanyName</th>
                            <th>Employee</th>
                            <th>Phonenum</th>
                            <th>Address1</th>
                            <th>Address2</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Zip</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                         <tr>
                             <td><input type="text" name="CompanyName_01"  /></td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="Employee_01"  /></td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="Phonenum_01"  /></td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="Address1_01"  /></td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="Address2_01"  /></td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="City_01"  /></td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="State_01"  /></td>
                             <td><input type="text" name="Zip_01"  /></td>
                             <td>&nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                     </tbody>
                 </table>
                <INPUT type="submit">
            </form>
            <input type="button" value="Add Row" id="add_ExpenseRow" />
        </div> <!-- END form_container -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Custom.js

```
$(function(){
    // GET ID OF last row and increment it by one
    var $lastChar =1, $newRow;
    $get_lastID = function(){
        var $id = $('#expense_table tr:last-child td:first-child input').attr("name");
        $lastChar = parseInt($id.substr($id.length - 2), 10);
        //console.log('GET id: ' + $lastChar + ' | $id :'+$id);
        $lastChar = $lastChar + 1;
        $newRow = "<tr> \
                       <td><input type='text' name='CompanyName_0"+$lastChar+"' /></td> \
                       <td><input type='text' name='Employee_0"+$lastChar+"' /></td> \
                       <td><input type='text' name='Phonenum_0"+$lastChar+"' /></td> \
                       <td><input type='text' name='Address1_0"+$lastChar+"' /></td> \
                       <td><input type='text' name='Address2_0"+$lastChar+"' /></td> \
                       <td><input type='text' name='City_0"+$lastChar+"' /></td> \
                       <td><input type='text' name='State_0"+$lastChar+"' /></td> \
                       <td><input type='text' name='Zip_0"+$lastChar+"' /></td> \
                       <td><input type='button' value='Delete' class='del_ExpenseRow' /></td> \
                   </tr>"
        return $newRow;
    }

    // ***** -- START ADDING NEW ROWS
    $('#add_ExpenseRow').live("click", function(){
        if($('#expense_table tr').size() <= 9){
            $get_lastID();
            $('#expense_table tbody').append($newRow);
        }else{
                alert("Reached Maximum Rows!");
        };
    });

    $(".del_ExpenseRow").live("click", function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        $lastChar = $lastChar-2;
    });
});
```

addemp.php  **This is were I am totally lost**

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($_POST['CompanyName_01']); $j++) {
    $CompanyName = $_POST['CompanyName_01'][$j];
    $Employee = $_POST['Employee_01'][$j];
    $Phonenum = $_POST['Phonenum_01'][$j];
    $Address1 = $_POST['Address1_01'][$j];
    $Address2 = $_POST['Address2_01'][$j];
    $City = $_POST['City_01'][$j];
    $State = $_POST['State_01'][$j];
    $Zip = $_POST['Zip_01'][$j];

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","USER","password","DATABASE");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql="INSERT INTO EmployeeInfo (CompanyName, Employee, Phonenum, Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip)
    VALUES('$CompanyName','$Employee','$Phonenum','$Address1','$Address2','$City','$State','$Zip')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";
}//end of the for loop
```

I need help building the php code to input to the database.
I have tried many different ways to read and write the data but am stuck.

I have tried changing the dynamically created text fields and to arrays however i cannot change the custom.js code to work right after.

My thought process as the code runs:

index.php creates CompanyName_01 , Employee_01. etc

Then when you hit add from custom.js creates the additional

CompanyName_02 , Employee_02. etc

CompanyName_03 , Employee_03. etc

So I would think in my addemp.php I could build an array with a while loop

```
<br>
$companyname_array CompanyName_0[i]<br>
$employee_array Employee_0[i]<br>
```

etc

Then use the variables create to add to my databases

However i cannot get any of the code i am trying to work.

Where am i going wrong.

Any help would be great.

Comment: you should probably take a look at http://knockoutjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your for loops syntax is a bit off :)

```
<?php
    for ($j = 1; $j < count($_POST['CompanyName_0']); $j++) {
        $CompanyName = $_POST['CompanyName_0$j'];
        $Employee = $_POST['Employee_0$j'];
        $Phonenum = $_POST['Phonenum_0$j'];
        $Address1 = $_POST['Address1_0$j'];
        $Address2 = $_POST['Address2_0$j'];
        $City = $_POST['City_0$j'];
        $State = $_POST['State_0$j'];
        $Zip = $_POST['Zip_0$j'];
    }
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
    for ($j = 1; $j < count($_POST['CompanyName_0']); $j++) {
        $CompanyName = $_POST['CompanyName_0'.$j];
        $Employee = $_POST['Employee_0'.$j];
        $Phonenum = $_POST['Phonenum_0'.$j];
        $Address1 = $_POST['Address1_0'.$j];
        $Address2 = $_POST['Address2_0'.$j];
        $City = $_POST['City_0'.$j];
        $State = $_POST['State_0'.$j];
        $Zip = $_POST['Zip_0'.$j];
    }
?>
```

after another look your connecting to mysql in every time the loop runs, put it before the loop. and i highly recommend using stmt->execute(); for looping entries

Comment: thanks for the editor, is there a possibly to use TAB in Stackover flow annoying to hit zillions of times space.

Comment: Type space four times, copy it and paste it a few times, paste twice for double tab ;). Otherwise use your IDE. By the way, your first example is wrong, you should use double qoutes `"`.

Comment: @bountyh Paste your code normally, mark it, and use the `{}` tool or Ctl-K to indent it as code.

Comment: The second option of this solution works the best. The first line is wrong it gave me an error "CompanyName_0" undefined so i changed the for to  "for ($j = 1; $j < $l; $j++)" $l being a variable that comes from the index page adding and subtracting if a user clicks add or delete. I also had to edit the way the custom page added text boxes to account for the user adding or subtracting. Thank So much this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append `[]` to your field names of your `input`. As such; `<input name="CompanyName[]">`

Then `$_POST['CompanyName']` will contain an array with all form fields. Which you can access by `$_POST['CompanyName'][$j]`.

This way you do not need to hardcode the form in jQuery, so now you can just clone the first row and append it to your table.

Also you are even looping the connection, so if you expand the form 8 times, the connection will be made 8 times which is really unnecessary. Place the connection above the loop.

It's good that you use `mysqli_*` but I recommend using the prepared statements as your code is unsafe.

And tables are generally not a good idea for constructing forms.